# Does Lyapunov function need to be defined at zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Consider the function $V(x,y) = x-y-y\ln \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$, where $x,y>0$ and $y$ is fixed. $V$ is constructed to study the stability of equilibrium point $x=y$ for the system $$ \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = y - x(t) .$$ Then it satisfies the properties of Lyapunov function, but not defined at zero. But in one of the textbook it is defined as Lyapunov function. Can we have Lyapunov function which is positive for all non zero points but not defined at zero?

Comment: No, it is not a Lyapunov function if it does not have a (strict) minimum. It can be a first integral (of some simple predator-prey or Lotka-Volterra system), which is also helpful to describe solutions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann If we take $V(x) = x-1-\ln(x),~x>0$, then it has minimum value at $x=1$. Is it Lyapunov function?

Comment: It could be, for an ODE that has a stationary point at $x=1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So, we don't need it to be defined at $0$. Also, $V(x,y)$ will be Lyapunov function function if $x=y$ is equilibrium point.

Comment: It depends on what your definition is. Often the denotation of "Lyapunov" is to the combination of function, ODE system and stationary/equilibrium point, so that without one of these data one could not say if a function is "Lyapunov". Your function has a saddle point at $(1,1)$, so it is of limited utility in proving the stability of an equilibrium.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Still, I am not getting it. You mean definition of Lyapunov function can vary according to our system of ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Yes. Without the relation to an ODE system the function just has a strict minimum at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lyapunov function needs only be defined in some neighborhood of the equilibrium point that is to be examined. So from that direction your function is admissible, if the equilibrium is at $(1,1)$, then the function values (and if they exist) on the coordinate axis are only of minor concern.

Note that your claim of positivity is wrong, you can write the function as $V(x,y)=f(x)-f(y)$ where $f(x)=x-1-\ln(x)$. As $f$ has a strict minimum at $x=1$, the values of $V(1,y)$ are negative for $y\ne 1$.

Comment: For the positivity, actually I am taking $x$ near to y. Here, $y$ is fixed and nothing but equilibrium point of the system.

Comment: This shows again that context is missing, without the concrete ODE it is not visible why that kind of restriction would be helpful.

Comment: $y$ is a variable, not a point. A fixed value for $y$ describes a line. As I said, context is missing.

Comment: Please check the edited question. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Now the equilibrium is indeed at $x=y$, but the minimum of the Lyapunov function is still at $x=1$, which is not the equilibrium point in question. In this sense it is still not a Lyapunov function.

Comment: I understand your point, there was silly mistake while defining $V$, I edited it again. Now, minimum is at $x=y$.

Comment: Yes, with that correction it now is a Lyapunov function around $x=y$.